# Java - BlackJack project - Problems with I/O and cycles

Tags: java, io, blackjack

I'm trying to make a simple `BlackJack` game driven by character input and I'm having a lot of problems in the later part it.

I commented the part that's giving me troubles, the rest doesn't seem to have errors and I did unit test it.
So, what did I do? I created a class that holds the cards drawn and manages them, table, player and dealer are both instances of table. 
A table has max 5 cards(for simplicity), every card object comes from the Card class that has a method to add data to the card object.

The main class drives the program and the decisions are made with a character input from the keyboard, I get problems at that point.

```
    import java.io.IOException;

class Table{
    Card[] hand = new Card[5];
    int counter = 1;

    Table() {
        for ( int i=0; i<hand.length; i++) {
            hand[i]=new Card();
        }
        hand[0].GetCard();


    }

    void ReadCards(){
        for(int i= 0;i<counter;i++ ) {
            System.out.println("The card "+(i+1)+" is " + hand[i].name + " "+ hand[i].seed + "."  );

        }
    }
    void DrawCards() {
        hand[counter].GetCard();
        counter++;
    }
    boolean isOut() {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i= 0;i<counter;i++ ) {
            sum += hand[i].value; 
            if(sum >21) {
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }

    int TheSum() {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i= 0;i<counter;i++ ) {
            sum += hand[i].value; 


        }
        return sum;
    }

    boolean isWIN(Table p2) {
        int sum = 0;
        int sump2 = 0;
        for(int i= 0;i<counter;i++ ) {
            sum += hand[i].value; 


        }
        for(int i= 0;i<p2.counter;i++ ) {
            sump2 += p2.hand[i].value; 


        }
        if (sum>sump2) {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }



    class Card {
        public int value = 0;
        public String name = "";
        public String seed = ""; 



        void GetCard(){
            int positive = 0;
            do {
                positive = (int) (Math.random()*100) % 10;
            }while(positive == 0 );
            value = positive;
            if(value<10) {
                name = String.valueOf(value);
            }
            else {
                positive = 0;
                do {
                    positive = (int) (Math.random()*100) % 3;
                }while(positive == 0 );
                switch(positive) {
                case 1:
                    name = "J";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    name = "Q";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    name ="K";
                    break;

                }


            }
            positive = 0;
            do {
                positive = (int) (Math.random()*100) % 4;
            }while(positive == 0 );
            switch(positive) {
            case 1:
                seed = "CLUB";
                break;
            case 2:
                seed = "DIAMOND";
                break;
            case 3:
                seed ="SPADE";
                break;
            case 4:
                seed ="HEART";
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}



public class BlackJack {
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException {


        System.out.println("Welcome to the BlackJack's table! Press y to start! ");
        char flag;
        do {
        flag = (char)System.in.read();

        }while(flag != 'y' );
        Table dealer = new Table();
        Table player = new Table();
        System.out.println("DEALER");
        dealer.ReadCards();
        System.out.println("PLAYER");
        player.ReadCards();
        flag = ' ';
        System.out.println("Do you want to draw a card? I'll draw until you'll press n");
/*
        flag = (char)System.in.read();
        while(flag != 'n' ) {
            player.DrawCards();
            player.ReadCards();
            if (player.isOut()) {
                System.out.println("YOU LOSE");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            flag = (char)System.in.read();
        }
        System.out.println("The dealer will draw");
        while(dealer.TheSum()<18) {
            dealer.DrawCards();
            dealer.ReadCards();
            if (dealer.isOut()) {
                System.out.println("YOU WIN");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
*/
        System.out.println("WHO WON?");

        if (player.isWIN(dealer)){
            System.out.println("YOU WIN");
        }
        else System.out.println("YOU LOSE");

    }
}
```

And yes, I'm not used to java. 
[Console screenshot of the output here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlEuv.jpg)

Comment: Just a question, is this for an assignment? Or for personal learning.

Comment: You should take a look at [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Personal learning, I avoided java for years, a week ago I bought a book and here I am.
I'm wondering mostly if I'm using wrong I/O methods, since there are too many of them and I can't figure out why it just jump my request where I started the comments. I'm already missing c++, c#, python.

Comment: If it's too much code I could just ask about I/O, but then scanner didn't work, leaving me in an infinite loop after pressing 'y', bufferedinputstream had the same effect. Those are the suggestions I saw.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of fixing your looping issues, however there may be some issue with the game logic, which is out of the scope of this question.

```
   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the BlackJack's table! Press y to start! ");
        char flag;
        do {
            flag = (char) s.nextLine().charAt(0);

        } while (flag != 'y');
        Table dealer = new Table();
        Table player = new Table();
        System.out.println("DEALER");
        dealer.ReadCards();
        System.out.println("PLAYER");
        player.ReadCards();
        flag = ' ';
        System.out.println("Do you want to draw a card? I'll draw until you'll press n");

        while (true) {
            flag = s.nextLine().charAt(0);

            if (flag == 'n') {
                break;
            }

            player.DrawCards();
            player.ReadCards();
            if (player.isOut()) {
                System.out.println("YOU LOSE");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            System.out.println("The dealer will draw");
            while (dealer.TheSum() < 18) {
                dealer.DrawCards();
                dealer.ReadCards();
                if (dealer.isOut()) {
                    System.out.println("YOU WIN");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }

            System.out.println(String.format("The dealer has finished drawing. Dealers score %d. Your score %d", dealer.TheSum(), player.TheSum()));
        }

        System.out.println("WHO WON?");

        if (player.isWIN(dealer)) {
            System.out.println("YOU WIN");
        } else {
            System.out.println("YOU LOSE");
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Welcome to the BlackJack's table! Press y to start! 
y
DEALER
The card 1 is 8 CLUB.
PLAYER
The card 1 is 2 SPADE.
Do you want to draw a card? I'll draw until you'll press n
n
WHO WON?
YOU LOSE
```

Comment: Yeah, probably there is some problems in the game, I hardly know the game myself after all, it's just the simpler thing I thought about in the moment.The program has still problems with that cycle, if I press something other than n it crashes, n jumps the dealer turn. 
I wonder why it's so hard to get a character input.

Comment: Well you have to enter a character, if you just press enter you'll get index out of bounds as it uses charAt(0), which looks at the first character.